# Alternative to many if / else statements in JS / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, if-statement

I am trying to compare many page elements from their initial values to what they are changed by the user, to prompt them to save etc.

Is there a better way to do this check without many if / else statements? A switch doesn't work since there are many different values being check, instead of a single one with many cases. Any and all tips / pointers are welcome, thanks!

```
if ($('#InitialhidLeadType').val() != $('#hidLeadType').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidProductType').val() != $('#hidProductType').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidFixedFilterType').val() != $('#hidFixedFilterType').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMinCreditScore').val() != $('#hidMinCreditScore').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMaxCreditScore').val() != $('#hidMaxCreditScore').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMinLoanAmount').val() != $('#hidMinLoanAmount').val())
        bIsChange = true;

    else if ($('#InitialhidMinLTV').val() != $('#hidMinLTV').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMaxLTV').val() != $('#hidMaxLTV').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMinCLTV').val() != $('#hidMinCLTV').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMaxCLTV').val() != $('#hidMaxCLTV').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidPropertyType').val() != $('#hidPropertyType').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidPropertyUse').val() != $('#hidPropertyUse').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidBankruptcy').val() != $('#hidBankruptcy').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidForeclosure').val() != $('#hidForeclosure').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidLoanPurpose').val() != $('#hidLoanPurpose').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidIsCashout').val() != $.trim($('#hidIsCashout').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidNoCreditScore').val() != $.trim($('#hidNoCreditScore').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidRelationship').val() != $.trim($('#hidRelationship').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidCurrentLoanVA').val() != $.trim($('#hidCurrentLoanVA').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidFoundHome').val() != $.trim($('#hidFoundHome').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidFHA').val() != $.trim($('#hidFHA').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidIsConforming').val() != $.trim($('#hidIsConforming').val()))
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidMSA').val() != $('#hidMSA').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidStatedCreditRating').val() != $('#hidStatedCreditRating').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidCampEffectivedate').val() != $('#hidCampEffectivedate').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidCampExpirationdate').val() != $('#hidCampExpirationdate').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidIsFixedFilter').val() != $('#hidIsFixedFilter').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidTestCompaign').val() != $('#hidTestCompaign').val())
        bIsChange = true;

    else if ($('#InitialhidSelectedStates').val() != $('#hidSelectedStates').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidVolumeTieredPricing').val() != $('#hidVolumeTieredPricing').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidWeekDayCapacity').val() != $('#filterCapacity').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidWeekendCapacity').val() != $('#filterCapacityWeekEnd').val())
        bIsChange = true;
    else if ($('#InitialhidHolidayCapacity').val() != $('#filterCapacityHoliday').val())
        bIsChange = true;

///////////////////////////////////// HTML Below //////////////////////////////////////

<div id = "changeCheck">

<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidLeadType" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidProductType" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidFixedFilterType" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMinCreditScore" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMaxCreditScore" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMinLoanAmount" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMaxLoanAmount" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMinLTV" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMaxLTV" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMinCLTV" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMaxCLTV" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidWeekDayCapacity" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidWeekEndCapacity" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidHolidayCapacity" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidPropertyType" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidPropertyUse" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidBankruptcy" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidForeclosure" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidLoanPurpose" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidIsCashout" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidNoCreditScore" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidRelationship" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidCurrentLoanVA" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidFoundHome" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidFHA" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidIsConforming" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidMSA" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidStatedCreditRating" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidCampEffectivedate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidCampExpirationdate" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidIsFixedFilter" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidTestCompaign" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidSelectedStates" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="InitialhidVolumeTieredPricing" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review

Comment: Can you post the html asweel? im pretty sure we can find you a way arround!

Comment: Yes the HTML would be helpful - for example, if your hidden inputs are direct siblings to the actual inputs, you could just have one function that takes in a jQuery object and compares it to the next() element and pass your inputs to that function

Comment: You might consider posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just added the HTML, massive thanks to all the fantastic responses so far, looks like there are a lot of different approaches to take!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterate the elements, compare each one, and if there are changes, prompt the user to save:

```
var save = false;

$('[id^="Initial"]').each(function() {
    if ( this.value != $('#'+this.id.replace('Initial','')).val()) save = true;
});

if (save) confirm(' would you like to save ');
```

Normally you'd solve this a different way, by changing a variable when the element is changed, and not with a check of all elements at some time:

```
var save = false;

$(':input').on('change', function() {
    save = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (save) confirm(' would you like to save ');
}
```

Comment: Your different approach wouldn't detect changing the field back though…

Comment: @Bergi - nope, only if changes where made

Comment: I mean when somebody edits an input field, `change` triggers, then he reverts his edit and then clicks `submit`. OP's script would not post the already stored data again, while yours says that they were changed.

Comment: @Bergi - yeah, I got it, it detects if changes where made, regardless of wehter or not the changed elements where changed back to default etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change your approach.  Rather than checking all the values for changes, intercept the `change` event for your form to set your flag when an input is changed:

```
$('#some-form-element').on('change', function (e) {
    // ... set flag here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This would tell you if any form elements had their value changed at any point.

```
var formIsDirty = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input').change(function() {
        formIsDirty = true;
    });
});
```

Of course, if they change the value back to the original value, it won't tell you that. If that isn't enough, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':input').each(function() {
        $(this).data('original', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Then when you validate:

```
    var formIsDirty = false;
    $(':input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('original') != $(this).val()) {
            formIsDirty = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The second option would let you do away with your hidden "initial values" fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var map = [
    ['#InitialhidLeadType', '#hidLeadType'],
    ['#InitialhidProductType', '#hidProductType'],
    ['#InitialhidFixedFilterType', '#hidProductType']
    // etc..
];
for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    if ($(map[i][0]).val() != $(map[i][1]).val()) {
        bIsChange = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a combination of the two approaches that adeneo and ACEfanatic02 suggested . . . with a twist:

```
$("input:visible").change(function() {
    var currID = $(this).prop("id");
    var initialValContainer = $("#Initial" + currID);

    if (initialValContainer.length > 0) {
        var currVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        var initialVal = $.trim(initialValContainer.val());

        if (currVal === initialVal) {
            $(this).addClass("changed");
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("changed");
        }
    }
});
```

At that point, whenever you are ready to check to see if you want to save, you can use the following code to see if it is necessary:

```
if ($(".changed").length > 0) {
    **prompt to save**
}
```

That way, the code will only prompt if at least one of the inputs has been tagged as changed.  This approach will also allow you to "untag" inputs that the user returns to their original value, as well as "reset" all the inputs if you need to with `$(".changed").removeClass("changed")` (e.g., if you are saving the new values without a page reload).